# How to use Kinesis to broadcast records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I know that Kinesis typical use case is event streaming, however we'd like to use it to broadcast some information to have it in near real time in some apps besides making it available for further stream processing. KCL seems to be the only viable option to use Kinesis as stream API is too low level.

As far I understand to use KCL we'd have to generate random applicationId so all apps could receive all the data, but this means creating a new DynamoDB table each time an application starts. Of course we can perform clean up when application stops but when application doesn't stop gracefully there would be DynamoDB table hanging around.

Is there a way/pattern to use Kinesis streams in a broadcast fashion?

Comment: Also keep in mind there's a [limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html) of 5 read transactions per second per shard (vs 1000 for writes), which will severely limit the number of applications reading directly from the stream.

Comment: kinesis isn't designed for having a lot of consumers ala 'broadcast' - Assuming your record producer is making use of Kinesis bandwidth, your stream readers are very likely to get throttled if you have more than a 1:2 producer-consumer ratio. If you're not using the full stream bandwidth, there are probably cheaper solutions - will [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) work for your use case?